# Computer or iPhone glitch

Tags: iphone, windows

My computer recognizes my iPhone 5 but not my iPhone 4 and yet both are recognized by iTunes.

I've tried all the received suggestions: restarting the computer and iPhone 4, changing the USB cable, changing ports- but to no avail.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Is iTunes running on this same computer?  Meaning iTunes on computer#1 recognizes both my iPhone 4 and 5, but the computer doesn't?  What specifically are you expecting the computer to recognize?

Comment: Yes, iTunes is running and recognizes my computer. What I'd like to see is my iPhone 4 icon appear on my computer so that I can add or download pics

Answer (score 1):

Your iPhone 4 needs to generate a pairing record and trust the computer.

First go through each of the steps. Don't skip steps and do them in order.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204095

If you don't see this message when you try to sync the phone over USB with iTunes, then you can remove all pairing records as follows:

1. Back up iPhone 4 (to the cloud or a computer)
2. Erase iPhone 4 (settings -> erase all content and settings)
3. Restore the backup to iPhone 4
4. Connect iPhone 4 to the computer over USB and be sure you Trust when prompted on the iPhone.

If the above doesn't work, then restore the phone and repeat the third and further steps above.